# Laravel PHP: Keep the chosen dropdown option stay selected on View

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a homepage that contains a dropdown menu that allows the user to select a category and will display results depending on which option is chosen from the dropdown menu.

It is currently working fine in updating and displaying the correct results but now I've run into a minor issue where I want the dropdown to stay selected on the chosen category.  Normally I would put a simple line of code within my view such as

```
{{ Form::label('category', 'Category:') }}
{{ Form::select('category', array('option1' => 'Option1', 'option2' => 'Option2'), $video->category) }}
```

where `$video` is the model used in the controller.

However this situation is a little bit different because I need to pass the 'category' variable from within my controller so that the dropdown menu will stay on the selected category after the user makes their choice.

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $vdo = Video::query();
    $pic = Picture::query();
    if($category = Input::get('category')){
        $vdo->where('category', $category);
        $pic->where('category', $category);
    }

    $allvids = $vdo->paginate(10);
    $allpics = $pic->paginate(10);
    $data = compact('allvids','allpics');
    $this->layout->content = \View::make('home.pics_vids_overview',$data)->with('category', Input::get('category'));
}
```

**View:**

```
{{Form::open(array('route' => 'overview_select', 'files' => true)) }}    

<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('category', 'Category:') }}
{{ Form::select('category', array('Category1' => 'Category1', 'Category2' => 'Category2', 'Category3' => 'Category3', 'Category4' => 'Category4'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

I've tried several approaches in passing the chosen 'category' variable back to the dropdown so that it will stay on the chosen option after the user makes their choice but none of them have worked for me yet.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
{{ 
    Form::select(
       'category',
       array('Category1' => 'Category1', 'Category2' => 'Category2'),
       (isset($category) ? $category : 'Category1'),
       array('class' => 'form-control')
    )
}}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the dropdown box will always stay selected on 'Category1' after the user makes their choice and submits it.

Comment: You should pass the `$category` array otherwise by default `category1` will be selected.

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure how to pass the $category array from the controller to the form.

Comment: You are passing `$data`, just add `$data['category']=Input::get('category')` before you pass it using  `$this->layout->content =...`.

Comment: I added '$data['category'] = Input::get('category');' to my code right before I passed it to the '$this->layout->content=...' line of code and now it works perfectly,  Thank you so much @The Alpha!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Form::model` instead of `Form::open` to bind the model to the form and it will automatically pick up any values in the model:

```
{{ Form::model(array('route' => 'overview_select', 'files' => true)) }}
```

Comment: I tried this approach and it still reverts back to the first option in the dropdown box after the user submits their selection.